# Cant open a base 64 encoded pdf

Tags: pdf, encoding, base64

I'm trying to open a base64 encoded pdf sent back to me by a web service.
This is the response header

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
>   RESPONSE BODY
>  
>   {
>    "success": true,
>    "message": "",
>    "value": "SlZCRVJpMHhMamNLSmJXMX.....
>   }

I tried an online decoder 
http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp  to manually copy paste and convert the code.

when I save the resulting decoded text as a pdf and open it with adobe reader it gives a "not support or damaged file" error. 
I could be doing something wrong but I've looked around on the web and couldn't find anything. 
[Here is the link to txt string of pdf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=68793729774426730301)

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: and where is the response body?

Comment: Hey Uku. My bad. I've changed the post to include the response body and I've uploaded the 64base pdf as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is base64 encoded twice. To read it, you need to decode this twice as well. The web service should not be encoding it twice though. So, you should contact them to fix this.

Comment: The output of the pdf seems to be blank after decoding twice. Is this a server side fault or something to do with the decoding process?

Comment: works for me, i can open the pdf. i used base64 --decode on Linux. Do not rely on online tools, find something for your OS.